# Type-I Discrete Cosine Transform not defined/found in Julia 0.3.0?

Tags: julia

I recently tried to compute the Type-I DCT of an array in Julia using the `r2r` standard-library function, and got errors. I tried to execute the following minimal example:

```
dat = [5; 4; 3; 1];
r2r(dat, "FFTW.REDFT00")
```

I encountered this error message:

```
ERROR: r2r not defined
```

I can't figure out what this means. The `r2r` function is [supposedly built-in to Julia 0.3.0](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/base/#Base.FFTW.r2r), so how is it possible that it is giving a syntax error here? For comparison, the `dct` (Type-II discrete cosine transform) works properly on `dat`.

Or am I just doing a silly syntax error?

#### EDIT

I just tried it in Julia 0.2.1 and I got the same error. This significantly elevates the probability that I am simply being an idiot, and that the function is not broken. However, confirmation would be great! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r2r` is built-in, but that doesn't mean it's available under that name in the standard scope.  As the docs you linked say:

```
The following functions are defined within the Base.FFTW module.
```

And so:

```
julia> dat = [5; 4; 3; 1];

julia> FFTW.r2r(dat, FFTW.REDFT00)
4-element Array{Float64,1}:
 20.0
  5.0
 -1.0
  2.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I must have been doing something silly!